# Cache-Control and max-age not working

Tags: php, caching, yii, cache-control

I am using yii framework and I need to cache an action which displays images.

I set the control header to: `public, max-age=311040000`.

I tried my actions on xampp on windows, running apache 2.4 and I can see

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=311040000
```

It works fine on xampp, but on another machine using ubuntu and apache 2.4 I see:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
```

The max-age is not changing on the linux environment.

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: How did you set header Cache-Control? in htaccess or using php header() function or in html meta tag?